# Link Multiple Email Addresses to AD-Imported User Profile

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, user-profile-property, incoming-email, email-enabled-library

I am looking for a way to associate multiple email addresses with a single SharePoint user profile which was sync'd from AD (via AD Import). The purpose of this is so that incoming email from any of the addresses could be accepted by a SharePoint library that allows permission to that one user, and all of the incoming items would be identified as being from that user.

I do not want to just allow any address to send to the library, but I also don't want to have to create 10 different AD users to represent 10 different email addresses that may be sending to the library, especially if they all come from the same entity (and for organizational purposes it would be nice to have all those items showing as being from the same user anyway). We have one account in AD to represent this entity so I'd like to be able to associate multiple email addresses with it.

Does anyone know if this is possible? And/or does anyone know the internals on how SharePoint identifies an incoming email to associate it with a user profile? I'm assuming/have observed from testing that it checks the sender address against one or more profile fields - so far I've seen it associate an item to the user when sent from an email that matches the user's UPN, as well as when sent from the email populated in their Work Email field (obviously), but I don't know if there is some other logic going on there as well behind the scenes. Perhaps there is some other multi-valued property that would store all the user's proxyAddresses and be able to identify them that way?

Things I have tried so far include creating a custom multi-valued property to store multiple email addresses. I tried marking it as an "alias" field in the field properties (don't know if that matters here but from the description it seemed like it might), but still, an email address stored in that field was not successfully resolved to my user account. I've also tried just having the user sync with no changes (but with multiple addresses in AD proxyAddresses attribute) but again, only the primary (the one that populates the Work Email field) would be associated with the account - mail sent from one of the secondary addresses was rejected by the library.

This is for SharePoint Server 2016.

Any insight here would be extremely helpful.

EDIT: To clarify, I'm not using the Directory Management Service. This is just a basic incoming email setup (using "advanced mode", w/ the SMTP drop folder on a network share) without the Directory Management features.

Comment: I'm confused. Incoming Email creates a *Contact* in Active Directory. The UPSA isn't involved nor are User objects. If you had a User object with that email address, the email address wouldn't be able to be used with Incoming Email.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified - I edited the post to include that I am not using the Directory Management Service. Since our profiles are sync'd using AD Import, every profile in fact has to be an actual user because AD Import won't sync contacts. When the mail is received, any attachments are dropped in the library with a "created by" user of the person who sent the email. So it is identifying the sender via some profile property - that's the part I'm trying to figure out (how I can associate 2+ emails w/ the same profile).

Comment: Use the DMS. It will simplify this. The Mail property is single-valued in the UPSA as it is with Active Directory.

Comment: Interesting - I'll have to look into that. Can you elaborate a bit on how it would simplify things though? And would it help achieve the goal of 2+ emails being associated with one SharePoint user?

Comment: You would no longer use Users as your Library Email addresses. Instead, the DMS would create a Contact object in Active Directory with that assigned email. You cannot have >1 email address associated with a Library for incoming email.

Comment: I understand we can only have one email address associated with the library itself (i.e. one email we send *to* , per library ), my goal was to have multiple emails we could send *from* and have SharePoint see those as the same "user" when it received the documents (e.g. userA@domain.com and userB@domain.com both send email to libraryA@domain.com and SP shows both received emails in the doc.lib. as being from the same person). But it sounds like whether using the DMS or not, that is not possible due to SharePoint only being able to associate one email address with a given user/email sender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the RFC for mail only allows a single value for `From`. SharePoint takes this value and performs a comparison against the site's User Information List. If it finds a matching user *and* that user has permission, it accepts the email. Since there can only be a single value for both `From` per the RFC *and* in the UIL for a user, it isn't possible to accept email from multiple email addresses for a single user (i.e. using proxyAddresses).

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you Trevor for all your information, it has been very helpful.